# Is it OK to include a stylized reproduction of a copyrighted painting in a design?

Tags: copyright, legal

I'm working on an icon of a framed painting. I would like the painting to be immediately recognizable to the intended audience, and so am considering doing a stylized reproduction of a particular painting from scratch to include in the icon. The original painting is copyrighted. Is there any legal problem with doing this?

Comment: Just to check: are you sure the original painting itself is in copyright, rather than a particular photographic reproduction?

Comment: Yes, the painting itself was created some time in the last few decades and is copyright the artist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stylized or not, reproduction of copyrighted work is derivative and subject to the legal issues that brings. So short answer... ***No, it is NOT okay.***

You would be better off using a painting already in the Public Domain.

Comment: While I agree, "It's not OK" is perhaps a bit too broad. It certainly may be OK, but it does open you up to the potential for legal problems.

Answer (score 4):

A similar topic has been covered here:

[Is vectorizing an image copyright theft if the image is not CC/Public domain?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/is-vectorizing-an-image-copyright-theft-if-the-image-is-not-cc-public-domain)

Short version: Likely to not be OK.